# Error while updating and incrementing the value by 1

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to update my entry and increment it by 1. When I try to do it using CodeIgniter, it shows me an error.

This is my code:

```
$this->abc->update_by(1,array('group_count'=>"group_count+1")); 
//here group_count is an integer.
```

This is the error I get:

> Incorrect integer value: 'group_count+1' for column 'group_count' at row 1

How can I do this?

Comment: What's the column type of `group_count`? If it's `VARCHAR` you're not going to be able to do this.

Comment: Might work- cast(int)

Comment: `$this->abc->update_by(1, array('group_count'=> ++$this->abc->group_count));`

Comment: @u_mulder still not working :(

Comment: how about `"\`group_count\`+1"`

Comment: @Prasanth Incorrect integer value: '`group_count`+1' for column 'group_count' at row 1

Comment: @RocketHazmat its my_model that i am using to for CRUD

Comment: Why are you passing `1` as the first parameter?  Did you want, maybe, `update_all`?

Comment: The problem is with `MY_Model`.  It's trying to set the value to, literally, `'group_count+1'`, which is not an `int`.  They are not passing `,FALSE` to `set()` which tells CodeIgniter not to escape the string.  https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model/blob/master/core/MY_Model.php#L324 and http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert